# Stop input when empty line occurs in Python

Tags: python, input

I hope this is not a duplicate, I checked all suggested topics and couldn't find what I am looking for or is working.

I want to input as many strings as I want (amount not predefined) and as soon as an empty line occurs, the input should stop. What I've tried so far with no success:

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input()
    if inp.strip() == "":
        break
```

;

```
while True:
    inp = sys.stdin.readline()
    if inp == '\n':
        break
```

;

```
 while raw_input().strip()!="":
        inp = raw_input()
```

and such combinations of everything I could find on the Internet. Nothing works so far, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: The first one looks fine to me. Can you further describe how it isn't working? Are you getting an error message, or what?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. No, I'm not getting any errors, but the input doesn't stop even after I hit 5 empty lines, I must manually press CMD+D.

Comment: The 1st one WFM. Upgrade you code to a [mcve].

Comment: Try putting a `print(repr(inp))` in the loop. If `inp` contains some unusual characters, it might give you an idea of what they are.

Comment: Everything looks fine for the first code. I have run it,and it's working as expected.

Comment: Try printing out every line to the console/idle and then at least you can see what information python is processing. Especially print out an empty argument.

Comment: so the newline character in windows/linux/osx is different. try checking for `\n\r` as well as `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: I just tried it, all the given strings are printed back to me, including one '', but I can give further inputs and it won't stop... eg. 
1. 1. 1.

'1. 1. 1.'

2. 2. 2.

'2. 2. 2.'



''

Comment: The last one won’t work because you’re calling `raw_input()` twice: once to check for empty line, once to use the line, so you ignore every other line.

Comment: @ArmenB There is no platform that returns `\n\r`. It’s `\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on macOS, Linux, and other Unixes (and `\r` on Classic Mac 9 and earlier, but Python 2.7 doesn’t even run on that platform, so you don’t need to worry about it). At any rate, `strip()` will remove all of them.

Comment: Just tried all \n\r, \r, \n, it has no different result

Comment: If you're using python 3, then I suggest using `input()` instead of `raw_input`. Although since you haven't got an error, I would assume you're using python 2

Comment: @Dan If the OP is using Python 3, `raw_input` isn't even an option.

Comment: @vedsil Which version of your code did you try that with? If `repr(inp)` is `''`, that will match the `inp.strip() == ""` test, but it won’t match the `inp == '\n'` test.

Comment: Also, it’s usually better to test `if not inp.strip():` (an empty string is falsey, any other string is truthy). Besides being more idiomatic, and shorter, it also means you can’t make hard-to-spot typos like `"'"` (or, even worse, `""` with an invisible character in the middle).

Comment: @vedsil The first one is working in macOS. Just put a screenshot of what's happening in terminal.

Comment: @abarnert with all of them...

Comment: @NegiBabu added photo to the question (you can see where my input cursor is at the end) I just wanted to input 2 stings and new line and continue with the execution of my program...

Comment: The screen shot is useless without the *exact* code you are running to produce that.

Comment: @abarnert I actually changed it with the last thing you mentioned and it finally worked..... very curious... THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 3):

The two-argument form of `iter` is almost made for this:

```
for line in iter(raw_input, ""):
    print "You input", line
```

Comment: @vedsil Can you show you input for that. It works for me and it's one of the neatest way I can imagine.

Comment: this solution works, I just tried it. Place your text in file.txt and run like so: `python script.py < file.txt`

Comment: @ArmenB Sure, but the original version _also_ works, so that doesn’t really prove much. The OP is doing something wrong, and changing to use `iter`, while a good idea in its own right, is only going to fix things by accident, if the OP happens to fix the problem he hasn’t shown us whole making this change to the code he has…

Comment: @abarnert, I am not sure what you mean fix by accident here

Comment: @ArmenB For example, let’s say the problem is that the OP’s actual code is testing against `"'"`, a hard-to-spot typo,  but the code they pasted in the question here has `""`, which is why that code works for everyone else, but the code the OP is actually running doesn’t work. If so, changing to use `iter` instead of an explicit loop won’t fix anything—but the act of copying and pasting the code or rewriting it may eliminate the typo, fixing the problem accidentally.

Answer (score -1):

You can check to see if the length of the line is 1 and the ascii character is 10 which is Line feed using `ord` you can break it then.